Background image with a pattern is misaligned, how can I solve it?
I'm trying to create a simple background pattern for a div using background-image. The pattern consists of diagonal lines designed to repeat seamlessly across the entire div. However, when the image repeats, the diagonal lines don't align properly, and there's a noticeable misalignment where the tiles meet, creating a break in the pattern.
I've checked my SVG file in Illustrator by repeating the pattern in a grid, and it aligns perfectly there. However, in the browser, it appears misaligned.

(left): pattern I'm using, (right): example in illustrator that is matching


pattern in the website
CSS code:
.about-pattern-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 55%;
    height: 250px;
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: url("./images/line-pattern-2.svg");
    background-size: 5%;
    right: 7%;
}

SVG file:
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 150 150">
    <path d="M10,10 L90,10 L90,90 L10,90 Z" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>


why an SVG? it's an easy task for gradients Check the background I am using here: https://css-pattern.com/

Your example SVG doesn't show the illustrated diagonal stripe pattern. Please update your post description. Quite likely, the misaligned tiles are caused by rounding errors introduced by percentage based size values.
